# Why is the maximum functional $f \mapsto \max_{t \in [0,1]} f(t)$ continuous on $C[0,1]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Define the maximum functional on the normed space $(C[0,1], \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ as follows:
$$
m: C[0,1] \to \mathbb R, \quad f \mapsto m(f) := \max_{t \in [0,1]} f(t).
$$
Why then is $m$ continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can write $m$ as composition of norms and other (trivially?) continuous functions:
$$
m(f) = \Big\|f + \|f\|_\infty \Big\|_\infty - \|f\|_\infty,
$$
where I used that $f+ \|f\|_\infty\ge0$.

Comment: That's slick. Clear from the representation. It took me a bit to realize why $m(f) + \| f \|_{\infty} = \big\| f + \| f \|_\infty \big\|_\infty$ holds, but now I've got it.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f, g \in X= (\mathcal C[0,1],\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty)$ and $t \in [0,1]$. You have

$$ f(t) - \Vert f-g \Vert_\infty \le g(t) \le f(t) + \Vert f-g \Vert_\infty.$$ Hence

$$\sup\limits_{t \in [a,b]} f(t) - \Vert f-g \Vert_\infty  \le \sup\limits_{t \in [a,b]} g(t)\le \sup\limits_{t \in [a,b]} f(t) + \Vert f-g \Vert_\infty.$$

From there the required continuity follows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The two proofs above are nice. Here's a direct proof of the continuity of $f \mapsto m(f)=\max_{t \in [0,1]}f(t)$ via the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity.

---

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Let $f,g \in C[0,1]$ such that $\|f - g\|_\infty \leq \delta := \varepsilon /4$.

Let $t_0, t_1 \in [0,1]$ be the maximum points of $f$ and $g$ respectively. That is $m(f) = f(t_0)$, $m(g) = g(t_1)$.

**Case** $m(f) \leq m(g)$**:**

Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
&g(t_0) - \varepsilon/4 \leq m(f) \leq m(g) \leq f(t_1) + \varepsilon/4 \\
\Rightarrow \quad &|g(t_0) - f(t_1)| \leq \varepsilon /2.
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
|m(f) - m(g)| &= |f(t_0) - g(t_1)| \\
&= |f(t_0) - g(t_1)| \\
&= |f(t_0) - g(t_0) + g(t_0) - f(t_1) + f(t_1) - g(t_1)| \\
&\leq \underbrace{|f(t_0) - g(t_0)|}_{\leq \varepsilon/4} + \underbrace{|g(t_0) - f(t_1)|}_{\leq \varepsilon/2} + \underbrace{|f(t_1) - g(t_1)|}_{\leq \varepsilon/4} \leq \varepsilon. \quad \checkmark
\end{aligned}
$$

**Case** $m(g) \leq m(f)$**:**

By symmetry, the same argument holds as in the first case. (Just swap $f$ with $g$ and $t_0$ with $t_1$.) $\quad \checkmark$

In all, we've shown the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity -- i.e. $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \quad \exists \delta > 0 : \|f-g\|_\infty < \delta \Rightarrow |m(f) - m(g)| \leq \varepsilon$.